# What is the correct way to link against shared libraries?

Tags: c, linker

I'm cross compiling a C application and am linking against the alsa library with `-lasound`

My newest cross compiler said it can't find the library, so I went exploring in the compiler's library directories and found.

`libasound.la`
`libasound.so.2`
`libasound.so.2.0.0`

I did not find a `libasound.so`, so to work around my problem i created a sym link

`ln -s libasound.so.2.0.0 libasound.so`

and everything appears to be okay now.  I am positive this is not the right way to do this though. Am I supposed to use different linker options to link against this? And what do each of the different `libasound.*` files mean?

Comment: "My newest cross compiler" -- from which vendor?  Is it `gcc` or `gcc`-based?

Comment: "I am positive this is not the right way to do this though" - I am going to disappoint you: it is.

Comment: Yea it's gcc, released by the angstrom distribution as a complete toolchain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most usual name of libraries in Linux is:

- The real library is `libasound.so.2.0.0`. The last 3 numbers is the library version (major.minor.revision).
- `libasound.so.2` is a symbolic link to the preferred (latest) 2.* version of the library, should you have more than one installed in the system. It is assumed that all the 2.* version are backwards binary compatible.
- `libasound.la` is a text file with a lot of information about the library to be used with `libtool`. Useful if you use `libtool` and the other autotools.
- `libasound.so` is a symbolic link to the library to be used by the toolchain. This is the file looked for when you link with `-lasound`.

You are missing the last one, maybe because in debian based systems it is installed only with the `libasound-dev` package. You can simply create it manually. It is not needed during runtime because the library has a `SONAME` entry in the header:

```
$ objdump -x /usr/lib/libasound.so | grep SONAME
  SONAME               libasound.so.2
```

That makes the dynamic linker look for that name at runtime, no matter what compiler options you used.

I hope I made some sense of this, because it is a bit complicated...

Comment: That did make a lot of sense. Thanks.